# How to loop over a 2d array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop over a 2D array getting the first and second value from each `row` to update a table

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_update_arrangement(input_arrangementid int, input_NAME text, input_price money, input_expirationdate date, products int[][])
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  UPDATE arrangement SET "NAME" = $2, price = $3, expirationdate = $4 WHERE arrangementid = $1;
  -- loop through array getting the first and second value
  -- UPDATE productinarrangement SET amount = arrayinputnumber2 WHERE productid = arrayinputnumber1 AND arrangementid = $1
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

With help I got the function call right, which doesn't return errors anymore. I don't understand how I can loop through the array getting the values within? I've commented out the lines and I don't know what to do. I call the function within this line:

```sql
SELECT fc_update_arrangement(1::int,'tom'::text,15::money,now()::date,array[array[1,2],array[3,4]]);
```

Comment: @VaoTsun im really sorry, i noticed an error in calling the function(i asked for money but was sending an int)  and was afraid I would get roasted for that

Answer (score 3):

There is an example in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

```
CREATE FUNCTION scan_rows(int[]) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  x int[];
BEGIN
  FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'row = %', x;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT scan_rows(ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]);

NOTICE:  row = {1,2,3}
NOTICE:  row = {4,5,6}
NOTICE:  row = {7,8,9}
NOTICE:  row = {10,11,12}
```

To try a verbal description: If the array of of type `whatever[]` and you loop with `SLICE 1`, the array gets cut into slices of one element each. The loop variable then will contain arrays of the same type `whatever[]`, each containing a single element of the original array. If you choose `SLICE 2`, the loop variable will contain arrays of size 2.

Comment: This works and gives me exactly the output you listed below the call of the scan_rows function. However I want to get the single values out. So:

row = {1,2,3} should return me:

1
2
3

as single numbers, not as a combination

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Looping through the values in `x` is straightforward and left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It works, but could you please tell me what the value of `SLICE` means here? I have read the manual and have tried with some code but still haven't figured it out.

Comment: This is explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY). "*With a positive SLICE value, FOREACH iterates through slices of the array rather than single elements.*" So `SLICE 1` means that each iteration of the loop will get a one-element array for `x`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Honestly I still don't get it. Maybe I have a wrong understanding of what's a `SLICE` in Postgres. I will try to figure it out. Thank you all the same.

Comment: I tried a verbal description, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 1st and 2nd elements of each row from a 2D(two dimensional) array as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(_2D_arr INT[]) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
DECLARE
  temp INT[];
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 1 IN ARRAY _2d_arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', array_to_string(temp[1:2], ' ');
  END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Memos:

- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) explains `array_to_string()`.

Then, calling `my_func()` with a 2D array gets the 1st and 2nd elements of each row as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]);
INFO:  1 2
INFO:  4 5
INFO:  7 8
INFO:  10 11
 my_func
---------

(1 row)
```

This is the example with a [DO statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html):

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR[];
  _2d_arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY[
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
  ];
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 1 IN ARRAY _2d_arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', array_to_string(temp[1:2], ' ');
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```